# how to call javascript function on page load in mvc3

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-3, jquery

I have a javascript function

```
function relativeTime(time) {

var period = new Date(time);
var delta = new Date() - period;

if (delta <= 10000) {   // Less than 10 seconds ago
    return 'Just now';
}

var units = null;

var conversions = {
    millisecond: 1,     // ms -> ms
    second: 1000,   // ms -> sec
    minute: 60,         // sec -> min
    hour: 60,       // min -> hour
    day: 24,        // hour -> day
    month: 30,      // day -> month (roughly)
    year: 12            // month -> year
};

for (var key in conversions) {
    if (delta < conversions[key]) {
        break;
    }
    else {
        units = key;
        delta = delta / conversions[key];
    }
}

// Pluralize if necessary:

delta = Math.floor(delta);
if (delta !== 1) { units += 's'; }
return [delta, units, "ago"].join(' ');

}
```

that give relative time difference like facebook comment.

How can i call this function in my view. I am using mvc3.
i am getting time from database like,

```
        <span>
            @item.wallTimeStamp
        </span>
```

instead of that i want to call javascript function,

i have a tag

```
<span>
    //call javascript function that will display time difference in this tag
   </span>
```

how can i do that?

Comment: Sir, you have 8 Questions in your profile and you have not accepted a single one of them. You do not seem to reward others that help you :(

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, give the span id(or something else for identification)

```
<span id="relativeTime">
</span>
```

Then, using javascript, first calculate that relative time value using your function. Then, using [jQuery.text()](http://api.jquery.com/text/#text2), set that value inside span

```
<script>

$(document).ready(function() {
  var wallTimeStamp = '@item.wallTimeStamp';

  var relativeTimeValue = relativeTime(wallTimeStamp);

  $('#relativeTime').text(relativeTimeValue);
});

</scipt>
```

Code modification may be needed for multiple spans of that kind

Comment: What is the error? If there's error or parsing @item.wallTimeStamp string as Date  on client side, you may need to set correct format for it. That's upon you :)

Comment: Not getting value from database in var wallTimeStamp = '@item.wallTimeStamp'; how can i get @item.wallTimestamp value in function? Is there any way to get this?

Comment: Do you use Razor view engine? And during debug, do you really see that propety value is not null?

Comment: Yes i am using Razor view engine. i am not able to debug javascript function.

Comment: I meant debugging on server side. I tested exactly that code and it's working fine (setting value in source)

Answer (score 6):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
 //called when the document is ready
});
```

Comment: which one? You wanted to execute a js function when the document is loaded - you can execute it in the `ready(function() {..})`

Comment: This is JQuery syntax, Bhargav clearly isn't using the JQuery framework.

Comment: @Berry Ligtermoet he tagged it. Twice ;)

Comment: Yea my apologies, didnt see the tags :S

Answer (score 4):

To be sure that your javascript code runs when the DOM has loaded you must use the ready() method. Look [here](http://api.jquery.com/ready/) for some explanation. You can use also this shortahand notation for it:

```
$(function() {
    //put your code here
});
```

Answer (score 2):

```
<body onload="javascript:relativeTime(time);">
```

where `time` is whatever you want it to be.

If you want it as a clickable thing with an assigned value from your model, then do something like

```
<span onclick="relativeTime(@item.time)">@item.wallTimeStamp</span>
```

edit:

alright..

assuming your time in the function is coming from your model:

```
@HiddenFor(m => m.time)
```

create a seperate js file, and link it in your html doc:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="whatever.js"></script>
```

inside it (assuming you mean jquery):

```
$(function() {
    relativeTime($("#time").val());
});
```